# How to parse namespaces using untangle

Tags: perl, python-2.7, xml-parsing

I have been messing around in Python using the Untangle library (https://untangle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#) for easier calling of XML variables. It is pretty straight forward to me except when there are multiple xml headings that share the same name (like in the example XML below). In Perl, you could use something like the sample script below to parse XML files easily. I wish to use one line like this example does to grab a certain XML variable. i.e. use the name attribute as a child. I bet Untangle does thisin Python, but I have not figured it out yet.

Sample Perl script:

```
use XML::Simple;
my $XML = "/my/file/path/untest.xml";

my $config = XMLin("$XML", keyattr => { child => 'name'},forcearray => ['child']);

my $instance = 'child1';
my $things = $config->{child}->{$instance}->{thing};

print("the element: $things\n");
```

Sample XML file:

```
<root>
    <child name="child1">
        <thing>1</thing>
    </child>
    <child name="child2">
        <thing>2</thing>
    </child>
</root>
```

Edit: Edited the Sample Perl Script. This should work.

Comment: Is Untangle warning you against itself the same way as [XML::Simple](http://p3rl.org/XML::Simple) is?

Comment: Those aren't namespaces. They're just ordinary elements (in the default namespace) with identical names

Answer (score 0):

If there are several elements with the same name at the same level in your XML document then the value of that object attribute will be a *list*. That means you can access the data in your question like this

```
xml = untangle.parse(xml_file)

for child in xml.root.child:
    print "Name:  %s" % child['name']
    print "Thing: %s" % child.thing
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this in one line rather than a loop through the list. Example: $config->{child}->{$instance}->{thing};

Comment: No, because that can only display the details of a single `child` element. If you can't work it out yourself from there, then you must put in your question *exactly* the output you want